# Different forms of $(document).ready

Tags: jquery

I have seen people writing

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

and some writing

```
$(function() {

        });
```

What's the difference and when to use what?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`$` is the jQuery object itself, which when called implements a whole pile of different interfaces. `$('string')` runs a selector or constructs a node; `$(domElement)` wraps an element... and `$(a_function)` is a convenient short hand for `$(document).ready(a_function)`. See [the jQuery API docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core) for (much) more information.

A note in passing: `$(function () { ... })` is *shorter*, but if you ever want to search for all of your on-ready events, you might be wishing that you had `.ready` to search for :)

Answer (score 15):

**There is no difference.**

One is a convenient shorthand that calls the other internally.

From the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery):

> A shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.
>   Allows you to bind a function to be
>   executed when the DOM document has
>   finished loading. This function
>   behaves just like `$(document).ready()`,
>   in that it should be used to wrap
>   other `$()` operations on your page that
>   depend on the DOM being ready to be
>   operated on. While this function is,
>   technically, chainable - there really
>   isn't much use for chaining against
>   it.
>
> You can have as many `$(document).ready`
>   events on your page as you like. See
>   ready(Function) for details about the
>   ready event.