# Difference between $(fn) and $(document).ready(fn) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different forms of $(document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388043/different-forms-of-document-ready)
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)

What is the difference between the following two functions?:

```
$(function() { });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: No difference. First one is just a shortcut for the `ready` method.

Comment: That is what I figured but wanted to be sure, thanks. (Post that as an answer if you can.)

Comment: Seriously, this can be answered in 2 seconds by [looking at the api](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

Comment: Did not see the duplicates when looking, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ready is a handler function for use once the DOM is ready
The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute.
I would use `$(function() {});` normally.

`$(document).ready(function(){});` is typically used for anonymous functions

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended) 
$(handler)
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: `The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the attribute.`
What exactly does this mean?

Comment: looks like they took that text directly from the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), where the full sentence reads "The `.ready()` method is generally incompatible with the `<body onload="">` attribute." The following text, outlining the three ways of wiring up a DOM ready handler, is also from the documentation.